# How to hide user and pass in curl command in dockerfile

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile, password-protection

I Have a dockerfile and in one of last steps, I download a WAR file from artifactory, so I can use it in the containers in the webapps/ directory.

Thing is I don´t want to show user and pass of curl -u command. How can I hide both users and password in following command? Is there a way in docker to hide/encrypt passwords?

```
RUN curl -u user:pass -O "https://artifactory.xxxx.com:443/artifactory/api/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multi stage build to achieve a lightweight image, but you have to use one single docker build, instead of two. Like this single Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven as build
(... Your app build....)
FROM tomcat
COPY --from=build artifact.war /dest/dir
```

Everything before the second `FROM` is discarded from the resulting image, so it will contain Tomcat, not Maven, and your copied artifact.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the contents of RUN commands from `docker history`.

You should download the artifact outside the Dockerfile.  A script that did the `curl` command and then ran `docker build` might simplify things for you.  In addition to not exposing the credentials via `docker history`, this also avoids committing them to source control, makes it possible to build the image even if your Artifactory is unreachable, and simplifies a developer-oriented sequence where they need to build a temporary image out of something they've built themselves.

Comment: this is what I want to do and was ok so far:
Jenkins pipeline. Stage 1 code checkout , 2 build artifact.war 3 upload to artifactory . 4 docker build image and push it to azure regitry. Here in step 4 the docker image is built with the curl command to download it and leave it inside deploy folder. The way I want to do this is to use a slim image with just tomcat and java (Im using official tomcat dockerfile). a ligth image.  No maven here.So that´s why I build the artifact with maven in step 2 on jenkins during jenkins pipeline which already has maven.  what other aproach do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it could be done with this new BuildKit feature [RUN --mount=type=secret](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypesecret):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=creds,target=/tmp/artifactory.credentials \ 
curl -k /tmp/artifactory.credentials -O <URL>
# REST of the DockerFile
```

Then you can build this image like this:

```
docker build -secret id=creds,src=$HOME/creds/artifactory.curl .
```

Content of the `$HOME/creds/artifactory.curl`:

```
-u USER:PASS
```

For additional info on -k, please follow the [official documentation](https://everything.curl.dev/cmdline/passwords)

Answer (score 0):

The official cUrl documentation says **-K** not -k